# Javascript error of init() not defined . How to remove this error?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.10/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript">
        var map, layer;
        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map', {controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({documentDrag: true}),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
            ]} );
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    {layers: 'basic'} );
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <h1 id="title">OpenLayers Document Drag Example</h1>

    <div id="tags">
        drag
    </div>

    <div id="shortdesc">Keep on dragging even when the mouse cursor moves outside of the map</div>

    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>

    <div id="docs">
        <p>This example shows how to make a map draggable outside of the map itself.</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

That is my html code with the javascript . My firebug throws up the error init() not defined . What can be the error ?

Answer (score 4):

Your `<script>` element loads its content from an external resource (`http://openlayers.org/api/2.10/OpenLayers.js`) since you specified that URL in its `src` attribute.

Therefore, the browser will ignore the *actual* content of the element, so `init()` won't be defined.

Try using two `<script>` elements instead:

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.10/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, layer;
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map', {controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({documentDrag: true}),
            new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
        ]} );
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                {layers: 'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(layer);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you . Though the error went away , there is still no sign of the OpenLayers map being displayed .

Comment: I'm not familiar with Open Layers, but shouldn't the `'map'` argument be part of the object passed to `Map()`? Something like `Map({ div: "map", controls: ... });`?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/lite.html

It is the basic and simplest example of Openlayers.